# The type ResourcePatternResolver cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, red5

I am doing white board application in red5. The sample code is as follows

```
package com.free.whiteboard;

this.createSharedObject(app, "freehandSO", false); 
//Shared object for freehand drawing    
app.setAttribute("freehand" , new FreeHandDrawing(this));
```

and i am getting error in the last line, it says that

```
"The type org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver 
cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from   required 
.class files"..
```

Comment: Hi @Shajith : have u done the white board application using red5.Can u provide any sample tutorial or demo ,as i also have to implement the same thing in my project

Answer (score 8):

I know it's a month old but the answer has to do with eclipse not finding the spring-core-2.5.6.jar in your buildpath. just add that jar to your buildpath and you should be good to go.  Note - this only affects compilation - you don't have to deploy the jar itself to have your application work as Red5 already knows how to find that class.